How do I get csrfToken for front-end to submit logins using Django?
I've read all the issues about this, but it's still not clear to me.
I am not using Django templates with Django Rest Framework to handle login functions (login, logout, changepassword, create user, etc).
I tried POSTing to the accounts/login page with
"username": <user>,
"password": <password>

But it also wants a CsrfViewMiddleware token.  It's not clear to me where I get that.  Does the front-end have to request it first from another endpoint?  Is there some other way to do the CSR checking?
Update
I have tried getting a CSRF token using
@api_view(['GET'])
def csrf(request):
    return JsonResponse({'csrf': get_token(request)})

I then tried the accounts/login request setting this token in the body as csrfmiddlewaretoken.  I also sent it in the header as X-CSRFToken
{
    "username": "peter",
    "password": "test",
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "ze3OW730d8q0F5QcsH6UmW1yQu0Qj3wPWREofiyhw3H4FNrlZH0HUYfB1yhmriz8"
}

But I still get the error
        <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
        <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


Are you using regular Django views or DRF views?

I'm not exactly sure what the difference is, but I'm using DRF to create rest endpoints. All of my view functions are annotated like this @api_view(['POST'])

As long as you interact (auth, typically) with a client that supports cookies, Django will set a csrftoken-cookie. You can read this cookie on your frontend and include it in your POST.

EDIT:
If you're not interacting with any endpoint prior to sending the POST, you'll have to fetch the token in advance as you rightly speculated:
# views.py
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def csrf(request):
    return Response({'csrf': get_token(request)})

Alternatively, and I've not tested this explicitly, it is my understanding that any request you make to an endpoint with CSRF protection will yield a CSRF token, so long as the request isn't denied (or ends up in an exception). So in theory, you should be able to do make a lightweight request (HEAD or OPTIONS for example) to the endpoint and end up with a csrftoken cookie implicitly.

When the CSRF middleware enabled, the default is indeed to check every request for certain HTTP verbs. As for your continued troubles, have you configured any custom CSRF settings (like CSRF_HEADER_NAME)? In general, I think switching to token auth instead of session auth would be beneficial - CSRF doesn't apply in that case.

DRF has a good guide for it: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication
